# Is there a word to describe two people who have perfect "anti-chemistry"?

Tags: single-word-requests

- [Abbot and Costello](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTcRRaXV-fg)
- [Jaime Hyneman and Adam Savage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHmA4FeAa7I)
- [Conan O'Brien and Jordan Schlansky](https://youtu.be/6A8W77m-ZTw?t=1m21s)

You can say they are perfect foils for each other or are perfect rivals, but that's not really what I'm getting it. What word describes the perfect level of acrimony between two people, which would be the opposite of "chemistry"? Thesaurus suggests "repulsion" but that doesn't really capture the inherent feeling in the room when you see these people together. It's not that they have "bad chemistry" (don't work well together), it's that their hatred of each other motivates them and pushes them to succeed, so in the end they accomplishes as much as a pair with perfect "normal" chemistry. Maybe another way to describe "anti-chemistry" is bad chemistry that mutates into to good chemistry.

> Born from a mutual dislike, Adam and Jamie have great _________.

or

> Adam and Jamie's _________, born from mutual dislike, is tangible.

Comment: ***Opposites attract*** — *used to say that people who are very different from each other are often attracted to each other.* https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opposites%20attract

Comment: dark energy....

Comment: @ab2 I was thinking that too, but I think there's something more specific. The yin and yang answer is good in that regard.

Comment: Add a sample sentence else your question may get closed.

Comment: Is _animosity_ close enough?  Note that 'What word describes the perfect [ultimate] level of acrimony between two people?' and 'Adam and Jamie have great _________.' (which grades your required word) are incompatible.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That implies that they hate each other, but it doesn't show how they work well as a result.

Comment: I'm not sure that such a word (or such a situation) exists.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I put three links.

Comment: Your own term [*foil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foil_(literature)) captures this idea well. In your example sentences, *chemistry* still works. [Here's](http://nerdist.com/actors-acting-with-themselves-have-great-on-screen-chemistry/) an example of the use of the term *chemistry* in the context of a single actor who plays opposing roles in the same show.

Comment: I've seen Superman use heat vision to melt ice, but that doesn't mean that it was a real phenomenon. I doubt there's a word meaning 'use heat vision to melt ice'.

Comment: @Lawrence Foil is what they are to each other, but it doesn't describe their tangibly observed relationship, and how it is synergistic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Jaime and Adam are real people who actually don't get along well; same with Conan and Jordan, although the latter is slightly acting.

Comment: "We don't get along very well together on a personal level. In 25 years we've known each other, we've never had dinner alone together. We do not choose to hang out if we don't have to be in proximity, and yet, there's a couple of things that happened, and they're pretty remarkable." is hardly compatible with 'their hatred of each other motivates them and pushes them to succeed'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Abbot and Costello, the **yin and yang** of comedy, enjoyed fame in the 40s and 50s*.

> In Chinese philosophy, **yin and yang** (also yin–yang or yin yang, 陰陽 yīnyáng "dark–bright") describe how seemingly opposite or contrary forces may actually be complementary, interconnected, and interdependent in the natural world, and how they may give rise to each other as they interrelate to one another. 
>   - [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't fit the sentences I supposed, but I think **[antidotal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antidotal)** could work (i.e "Jamie and Adam are antidotal to each other.")

> **[Antidote](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antidote)**: something that relieves, prevents, or counteracts
>   [MWO]

Answer (score 0):

Mutual repulsion.

> Noun: **repulsion**  ri'púl-shun
>
> The force by which bodies repel one
> another
>
> - repulsive force   Intense aversion
> - repugnance, revulsion, horror   The act of repulsing or repelling an attack; a successful defensive stand
> - standoff

-- [WordWeb Online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=repulsion)

Answer (score -2):

I think discouragement or revulsion
**discouragement**:
Noun:-
-state of being discouraged
-act of discouraging

### -something that discourages

Detailed expression: -
-the feeling of despair in the face of obstacles

### -the expression of opposition and disapproval.

**revulsion**:
Noun 
-disgust, repugnance
-sudden change in feeling toward a particular subject
-withdrawal, act of drawing back
-act of drawing blood from one area to another through counterirritation (Medicine)

http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-opposite-of/chemistry.html

Comment: Welcome to ELU! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.